# Modelling precedence relations

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, scheduling, big-m

I have two tasks $i$ and $k$ with durations $d_i$ and $d_k$, where $d_i$ and $d_k$ are nonnegative variables.

I would like to model that $i$ may precede $k$ or $k$ may precede $i$ and that they may not overlap.

So, with $t_i$ and $t_k$ denoting the start times of $i$ and $k$, I have to model:

either $t_i + d_i \le t_k$   OR  $t_k + d_k \le t_i$

Introducing a binary variable $y$, I can achieve the result with the following two big M constraints:

$t_i + d_i - t_k \le M y $

$t_k + d_k - t_i \le M (1-y)$

If it is required that $t_i + d_i \le H $ and $t_k + d_k \le H $ then I can set $M$ to be $M=H$.

My question is, is what I have done so far correct (what worries me is the variable duration) and can anyone think about a better formulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and is the classical approach from [Manne, *On the Job-Shop Scheduling Problem* (1960)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.8.2.219).

In some modeling languages, you can also enforce these implications by using indicator constraints:
\begin{align}
y = 0 &\implies t_i + d_i \le t_k \\
y = 1 &\implies t_k + d_k \le t_i \\
\end{align}

Comment: Rob, thank you very much for your reply and the suggestion. I will try both the Big-M and the Indicator Constraint approach.

Answer (score 5):

You may also use [CPOptimizer within CPLEX](https://www.slideshare.net/PhilippeLaborie/an-introduction-to-cp-optimizer) that contains scheduling high level concepts. And then you can directly use noOverlap constraints.

In

```
using  CP;

dvar interval i size 5;
dvar interval k size 4;

dvar sequence seq in append(i,k);

minimize maxl(endOf(i),endOf(k));
subject to
{
  noOverlap(seq);
}
```

the constraint

```
noOverlap(seq);
```

makes sure that i and k do not overlap

and in the CPLEX IDE you will see

[image: view of seq in CPLEX IDE]

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone think about a better formulation?

Another option is to use binary variables $x_{it}$ that take value $1$ if task $i$ starts at time $t$. You then need two sets of constraints:

- one start time per task:
  $$
  \sum_{t}x_{it} = 1 \quad \forall i
  $$
- don't overlap tasks:
  $$
  \sum_{i}\sum_{k, t+1 - d_i \le k \le t}x_{ik} \le 1 \quad \forall t
  $$

This formulation is more tight and should solve faster. And it does not require big-Ms.

Comment: This however, will function only in the case of a discrete time formulation? Why is this formulation tighter?

Comment: Yes indeed this assumes a discrete time span. That seems reasonable to me. I don't think it is easy to prove that the formulation is tighter - this could be a great separate question. I only have empirical evidence to back this statement.