# How to model a non-overlap constraint between 2 groups of tasks?

Tags: modeling, constraint, scheduling

Let $T$ be a set of tasks. Each task $t \in T$ has a duration $d_t$.

Let $T_1 \subset T$ and $T_2 \subset T$ such as $T_1 \cap T_2 = \emptyset $

How can I model the following constraint : all tasks from $T_1$ cannot overlap all tasks of $T_2$ and vice versa. So basically, tasks from a same set can overlap but when a task from a set is performed, no task from the other set can overlap it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

within CPLEX you could try CPOptimizer and use intervals.

In OPL (One of CPLEX API) you could write

```
using CP;
int sizeT=10;
range T=1..sizeT;
int d[i in T]=i;

dvar interval t[i in T] size d[i];

{int} T1={i | i in T : i <=(sizeT div 2)};
{int} T2=asSet(T) diff T1;

subject to
{
  forall(i in T1,j in T2) overlapLength(t[i],t[j])==0;
}
```

and then see

[image: gantt view within CPLEX IDE]

This works and is a bit naive.

So a better way as far as solve speed is concerned is to rely on state functions:

```
using CP;
int sizeT=10;
range T=1..sizeT;
int d[i in T]=i;

dvar interval t[i in T] size d[i];

{int} T1={i | i in T : i <=(sizeT div 2)};
{int} T2=asSet(T) diff T1;

stateFunction s; // 1 or 2 according to T1 or T2

subject to
{
 
  forall(i in T1) alwaysEqual(s,t[i],1);
  forall(i in T2) alwaysEqual(s,t[i],2);
}
```

which will do the same but faster.

And you can see in the CPLEX IDE for s:

[image]

Comment: I am actually using CPOptimizer! Would this still be a good approach if there was around 30 pairs of sets of 10 tasks each ? Does the cardinality of the sets and the number of pairs of sets could change the choice of which modelisation to use for this constraint ? Thanks!

Comment: You should try the state function approach then

Answer (score 7):

One simple approach is to impose the classical non-overlap constraints for each pair of tasks for which one task is in $T_1$ and one task is in $T_2$, as shown [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/modelling-precedence-relations).

Comment: Would this still be a good approach if there was around 30 pairs of sets of 10 tasks each ? Does the cardinality of the sets and the number of pairs of sets could change the choice of which modelisation to use for this constraint ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the cardinalities could change which model performs best.  Are your durations and start times integer or arbitrary?

Comment: Durations are integer, they are given ($d_t$) while start time are variables.

Comment: In that case, I suspect that the generalization of @worldsmithhelper's model to multiple pairs of groups (instead of just one pair $(1,2)$) would do better.

Answer (score 4):

I assume for you have a binary matrix $S_{i,t}$ (tasks)$\times$(time steps) which tells you whether some task $i$ is active at time $t$. This approach introduces additional variables unless you have other parallelism constraints that can only be expressed in that format or of your objective depends on it like [it does here.](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6200/4777)

Define a new binary matrix of $G_{g,t}$(task groups)$\times$(time steps) and impose the constraints:

$$\forall t_i\in T_1 \forall t\in\text{Time}: S_{i,t} \leq G_{1,t}  $$

and similar for $T_2$. $G_{1,t}$ will be $1$ if any of the tasks in $T_1$ are active.  Now you can express constraints on which groups can be active at time $t$. In your case you want:

$$\forall t\in\text{Time}: G_{1,t} + G_{2,t} \leq 1$$